# Get value of field with same name using Sitecore powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

There are *two fields with the same name* `Title` in a Sitecore item, Is there a way to get the values of both fields using Sitecore PowerShell?

Comment: In Sitecore PowerShell, you can also get fields by their GUID - $_.Fields[<Field GUID here>]. As such, there will be no conflict even if multiple fields have same name. But it is not a good practice for 2 or more fields to have same name in a template. It can affect content authoring experience unless there is a way to differentiate between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can try to get the value of two fields of the same name. This is my item.

[image]

And this is the script

```
$item = Get-Item master:\content\home\new 

Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/content/home/new" |
    Show-ListView -property "Title",  @{Label="Title2"; Expression={$_.Fields["{76D4FC9B-ADC1-496E-AB3A-0264679D65A2}"].Value}}
```

In the above query for **Title2** label, I have given the field ID of the same field name.

And it will give me results like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have created two same field names `Title` as per your requirement.

[image]

And updated different content on different field

[image]

Below is the reference of PowerShell script to get both `Title` fieldx

```
Get-Item -Path master:/content/home  | Format-Table  -Property "Title",  @{Label="Title"; Expression={$_.Fields["BC04DED0-3D1C-4891-84CD-6FA42C8ADBB3"]} }
```

And result is:

[image]